# Pickling keyword arguments in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pickle

**Python 2** [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) says:

> Deprecated since version 2.3: Use function(*args, **keywords) instead
>   of apply(function, args, keywords) (see Unpacking Argument Lists).

[Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module requires the following syntax to define `__reduce__` method to dump an object:

```
def __reduce__():
     return (<A callable object>, <A tuple of arguments for the callable object.>)
```

*(I know that the length of tuple returned from `__reduce__` can be >2 but needs to be <=5. Considering the case of length 2 in the context of current question.)*

This means it is not possible to pass keyword arguments to the callable object. In Python 2, I have the following work-around:

```
def __reduce__():
     return (apply, (<A callable object>, ((<args>,), <kwargs>))
```

However, `builtins.apply` has been removed in **Python 3**. Is there any other alternative to implementing my own version of `builtins.apply` in **Python 3**?

Comment: Have you tried *? `return the_callable(*args, **kwargs)` ref: https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtins.html#removed-apply

Comment: `def apply(func, args, kwargs): return func(*args, **kwargs)` put this in a `utils.py`. Alternatively just wrap your functions so that it takes te arguments as you want: `def wrapper(func): return lambda args, kwargs: func(*args, **kwargs)` then instead of passing the callable pass `wrapper(callable)`.

Comment: @ferrix Doing `return the_callable(*args, **kwargs)` will call the function which will fail as __reduce__ return type should be `(callable, args)`.

Comment: Ah, right, my bad. Then @GiacomoAlzetta's solution will work.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Defining apply in `utils.py` or somewhere solves this issue. However, I was wondering whether any other work-around exists - be it through a third party library like `six`. Also, could you please elaborate the wrapper appraoch; possibly with a working example as an answer instead of in comments?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `functools.partial` for this:

```py
from functools import partial

def __reduce__():
     return (partial(<A callable object>, <kwargs>), ())
```